# How to efficiently extract fixed length string permutations from a character list?

Tags: c, string, permutation

I'm trying to create a function that populates an array from a character list such that the array will be composed of `n` length unique strings. Every possible permutation should be included. The working example below uses `n = 2` however I want to be able to vary `n` at runtime.

```
static char ULC[62] =   {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

static char pw[4096][2];    

for (int i = 0; i < 62; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 62; j++)
        {
        pw[i * 62 + j][0] = ULC[i];
        pw[i * 62 + j][1] = ULC[j];
        }   
    }
```

Obviously increasing `n` will require a much larger array but I'm just using a static array in the above example to simplify the code and explanation.  Ideally something that will work in visual studio C (not C++ and definitely not python, java etc).

Comment: Aside: 4096 is a _magic_number_.  It is just something big. `pw[62*62][2]` would be more clear - as a first step.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Code works but it's just an example, not what I want.  What I want is a function I can decide n at runtime.  Not fixed at 2 as in the above.

Comment: @poby recursion?

Comment: @MartinJames yeah recursion would be neat but I have spent hours and haven't been able to do it.

Comment: @poby  "I have spent hours and haven't been able to do it" --> post your recursive attempted code.

Comment: You need a random and unique string for each element ?

Comment: Well, I would start by allocating space effectively.  Calculate the number of permutations, (eg.in your example by counting down from 62 2 times and multiplying), in the usual way, (3782), then multiply by the number of expected chars  plus 1, (for NUL terminator, so in your case, 2+1=3 so 11346), and malloc the array space.

Comment: So, while there is free space in the current output array, you need to iterate an input array length len with an index, take the indexed char, put it into the next free space in the current output array, remove that char from the input array, (by overwriting it with the last input array element) and recurse with the new, shorter input array, then put the array back as it was.  Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite it like this, it should be fairly simple to make it completely dynamic:

```
const int num_chars = 62;
const int n = 3;
static char pwn[num_chars * num_chars * num_chars][n];

for (int i = 0; i < num_chars * num_chars * num_chars; ++i) {
    int val = i;
    for (int in = 0; in < n; ++in) {
        pwn[i][in] = ULC[val % num_chars];
        val /= num_chars;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Use malloc. A VLA of that size could easily overflow the stack.